# Cant separate jquery results in 2 textboxes

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, textbox

I have 2 textboxes that populate data from mysql from 2 differend tables.

The code does work so that it gets the data from both tables but it shows in both texboxes the same table results, now I want each table result in each 1 of the textboxes separated.

Im using an autocomplete function so it shows the results of the table when you start to type in the textbox.

I tryed to copy the function and make 2 of them with differend id's but then it only shows results in only 1 textbox, with only 1 function it shows results in both textboxes but from the same table.

HTML:

```
<table style="float:left; clear:both;">
    <tr>
        <td class="tdfilter">
            <label>Boekingsnummer</label>
            <input type="text" name="boekingsnummer" size="20" id="boekingsnummer" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tdfilter">
            <label>Naam klant</label> 
            <input type="text" name="naam_klant" size="20" id="naam_klant" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions2" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList2">
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>
</table>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
function lookup(inputString)
{
    if(inputString.length == 0)
    {
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    }    
    else     
    {    
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data)    
        {   
    if(data.length >0)    
    {    
        $('#suggestions').show();    
        $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
    }
        });
    }
}

function fill(thisValue) 
{
    $('.inputString').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('.suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root' ,'*', 'records');
if(!$db) 
{
// Show error if we cannot connect.        
echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
} 

else 
{
// Is there a posted query string?
if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) 
{
$queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
// Is the string length greater than 0?
if(strlen($queryString) >0) 
{
$query = $db->query("SELECT naam_klant FROM overboekingen WHERE naam_klant LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");     
$query2 = $db->query("SELECT boekingsnummer FROM overboekingen WHERE boekingsnummer LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");

if($query) 
{
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) 
{
echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->naam_klant.'\');">'.$result->naam_klant.'</li>';
}
}   

if($query2) 
{
while ($result2 = $query2 ->fetch_object()) 
{
echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result2->boekingsnummer.'\');">'.$result2->boekingsnummer.'</li>';
}
}

else 
{
echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
}
} 
else 
{
} // There is a queryString.
} 
else 
{
echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 textboxes autocomplete with data from 2 tabels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717206/2-textboxes-autocomplete-with-data-from-2-tabels)

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
setTimeout("$('.suggestions').hide();", 200);
```

should be:

```
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve

```
function lookup(inputObject, ) {
    var $td = $(inputObject).parent();
    if(inputObject.value.length == 0) {
        $td.find('.suggestionsBox').hide();

    } else {    
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputObject.value+""}, function(data){   
            if(data.length >0) {    
               $td.find('.suggestionsBox').show();    
               $td.find('.suggestionList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and in html:

```
<input type="text" name="boekingsnummer" size="20" id="boekingsnummer" onkeyup="lookup(this);" onblur="fill();" >
[...]
<input type="text" name="naam_klant" size="20" id="naam_klant" onkeyup="lookup(this);" onblur="fill();" >
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a parameter to identifying the table from the ajax call.

Change your html:

```
onkeyup="lookup(this.value);"
```

to :

```
onkeyup="lookup(this.id);"
```

In your jquery:

```
function lookup(id)
{
     inputString =  $('#'+id).val();
     tableName = id=='boekingsnummer' ? 'first' : 'second';

    if(inputString.length == 0)
    {
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    }    
    else     
    {    
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+"",tableName: ""+tableName+""}, function(data)    
        {   
    if(data.length >0)    
    {    
        $('#suggestions').show();    
        $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
    }
        });
    }
}
```

In your php you can check check table name:

```
if(strlen($queryString) >0) 
{
  if($_POST['tableName'] == 'first'){
    //get result from first table
}   
else if($_POST['tableName'] == 'second') {
  //get result from another table
}
```

Comment: I get the error in firebug: TypeError: e.val is not a function