# 2 textboxes autocomplete with data from 2 tabels

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I have this javascript code that should populate 2 textboxes with 2 seperated tables from mysql. Im using an auto complete function. I would like to know how I could populate each textbox seperated with its own differend table data.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function lookup(inputString)
{
    if(inputString.length == 0)
    {
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    }    
    else     
    {    
        $.post("sql_naam_klant.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data)    
        {   
    if(data.length >0)    
    {    
        $('#suggestions').show();    
        $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
    }
        });
    }
}

function lookup(inputString)
{
    if(inputString.length == 0)
    {
        $('#suggestions2').hide();
    }    
    else     
    {    
        $.post("sql_boekingsnummer.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data)    
        {   
    if(data.length >0)    
    {    
        $('#suggestions2').show();    
        $('#autoSuggestionsList2').html(data);
    }
        });
    }
}

function fill(thisValue) 
{
    $('.inputString').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('.suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
</script>
```

TEXTBOXES:

```
<td class="tdfilter">
            <label>Boekingsnummer</label>
            <input type="text" name="boekingsnummer" size="20" id="boekingsnummer" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tdfilter">
            <label>Naam klant</label> 
            <input type="text" name="naam_klant" size="20" id="naam_klant" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions2" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList2">
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rename the second function to lookup2 and call that from the second input box on key up. Right now the second is a redeclaration of lookup() and only boekingsnummers are searched.

Comment: Thank you verry much for your awnser, this solved my problem !